# Continuous line numbers in the output pdf

Tags: line-numbering, lineno

I am using the following code  :

```
   \documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
   \setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
     \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm}
     \setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip}
     \hoffset=-1.4cm
     \usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb}
     \usepackage{hyperref}
      \usepackage[running, pagewise]{lineno}
      \linenumbers
      \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
      \newtheorem{conjecture}[subsection]{Conjecture}
      \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
      \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
      \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
      \numberwithin{equation}{section}
      \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
      \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
       \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
       \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
     \input xy
    \xyoption{all}
     \begin{document}
     la la la \\
    \begin{theorem}
    If this is true, then that is true.\
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
    It's always true
    \end{proof}
    la la la 
    \end{document}
```

before \begin{document} and the output that is coming using lineno package is discrete lining. I want line numbers (in the left) for all  lines (including the gaps between the paragraphs). Please let me know if there is a way around this.

The output is as follows :[image]

I want that there should be line numbers between lines 2, 3 and 3,4 and 4,5 and each line after 5 where there is nothing written. Is there way to make it densely numbered? This is the journal typesetting format. Since the paper is long it will be useful for me to have  the line numbers similar to the journals style in the framework of my code or some other code (which do not  hamper the compilation)

Comment: numbering the variable size stretchy spaces beween items  would sem a bit odd, I don't think the lineno package can do that. Someone might attempt a solution anyway, it would be helpful if you provided an example document. Currently you just show some possibly urelated theorem  definitions and an unrelated (non latex syntax) loading of the xy package, but no actual test documnt showing where you want the line numbers to change.

Comment: Many conferences and journals where you can submit papers for review just put a sequence of constant distance line numbers in the margin. This is often inprecise because the line number falls in between two lines, but for purposes of labelling a review comment this is usually adequate and it is a simpler solution than trying to number actual lines. Maybe that could be a solution here as well?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have edited the post now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example of my comment under the question: the Association for Computing Machinery uses continuous line numbering for papers under review. These line numbers are not linked to the actual lines in the paper and may therefore be misaligned vertically.

In the code below I added the relevant parts from `acmart.cls` into the example document from the question. Basically a box with line numbers is constructed by repeatedly adding the next number until the box reached `\textheight`. Then this box is added to the page at the top left corner using `\put`. This is repeated for each page by adding the `\put` command in a header specification using `\fancyhdr`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip}
\hoffset=-1.4cm
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{conjecture}[subsection]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
% the code below is modified from acmart.cls
% source: https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart
% licensed under LPPL 1.3
\newsavebox{\ACM@linecount@bx}
\newlength\ACM@linecount@bxht
\newcount\ACM@linecount
\ACM@linecount\@ne\relax
\def\ACM@mk@linecount{%
    \savebox{\ACM@linecount@bx}[4em][t]{\parbox[t]{4em}{\normalfont
        \normalsize
        \setlength{\ACM@linecount@bxht}{0pt}%
        \loop{\color{red}\scriptsize\the\ACM@linecount}\\
        \global\advance\ACM@linecount by \@ne
        \addtolength{\ACM@linecount@bxht}{\baselineskip}%
        \ifdim\ACM@linecount@bxht<\textheight\repeat
        {\color{red}\scriptsize\the\ACM@linecount}\hfill
        \global\advance\ACM@linecount by \@ne}}}
\def\ACM@linecountL{%
  \ACM@mk@linecount
  \begin{picture}(0,0)%
    \put(-26,-18){\usebox{\ACM@linecount@bx}}%
  \end{picture}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\ACM@linecountL}
% end of code modified from acmart.cls
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
la la la \\
\begin{theorem}
If this is true, then that is true.\
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
It's always true
\end{proof}
la la la 
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

There are various parameters to modify.

- Start the numbers before the first line: adjust `\put(x,y)`. In the code below `\put(-26,-10)` puts the number 1 above the first line.
- Number range: this is determined by the total height of the box. The code does not use the real height, instead it is simulated by the length variable `\ACM@linecount@bxht` which is initialized to `0pt` at the start of the box and increased by `\baselineskip` after every number. By reducing the simulated increase you can fit more numbers before the box reaches `\textheight`. Trial and error leads to `0.855\baselineskip` for numbers 1-60.
- Distance between numbers: this can be set by adding a length to the linebreak `\\` after each number. Trial and error leads to `\\[-1.5pt]` to put the number 60 near the bottom of the page.
- Resetting the numbers each page: this can be done by putting the number counter initialization `\ACM@linecount\@ne\relax` inside of the macro that is called for each page header (`\ACM@mk@linecount`, `mk` means 'make').
- Line numbers on first page: the numbers are produced by a header. This header is only shown if `\pagestyle{fancy}` is in effect. Many documentclasses set `\pagestyle{plain}` for the first page and/or for the full document. You can redefine `plain` to use the `fancy` definitions (i.e., print the header and therefore the line numbers) using `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}` (note: this was already included in the first version of the answer above). It is also possible that a documentclass sets the page style to `empty` in which case you should modify the header settings accordingly.

Modified code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip}
\hoffset=-1.4cm
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{conjecture}[subsection]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
% the code below is modified from acmart.cls
% source: https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart
% licensed under LPPL 1.3
\newsavebox{\ACM@linecount@bx}
\newlength\ACM@linecount@bxht
\newcount\ACM@linecount
%\ACM@linecount\@ne\relax
\def\ACM@mk@linecount{%
    \ACM@linecount\@ne\relax % reset counter each page
    \savebox{\ACM@linecount@bx}[4em][t]{\parbox[t]{4em}{\normalfont
        \normalsize
        \setlength{\ACM@linecount@bxht}{0pt}%
        \loop{\color{red}\scriptsize\the\ACM@linecount}\\[-1.5pt] % vertical distance between numbers
        \global\advance\ACM@linecount by \@ne
        \addtolength{\ACM@linecount@bxht}{0.855\baselineskip}% reduce similated box height increase
        \ifdim\ACM@linecount@bxht<\textheight\repeat
        {\color{red}\scriptsize\the\ACM@linecount}\hfill
        \global\advance\ACM@linecount by \@ne}}}
\def\ACM@linecountL{%
  \ACM@mk@linecount
  \begin{picture}(0,0)%
    \put(-26,-10){\usebox{\ACM@linecount@bx}}% x,y coordinates of line number 1
  \end{picture}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\ACM@linecountL}
% end of code modified from acmart.cls
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % add numbers to plain pages (e.g., first page)
\makeatother
\begin{document}
la la la \\
\begin{theorem}
If this is true, then that is true.\
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
It's always true
\end{proof}
la la la 
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Result (end of page 1 and start of page 2):

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you please kindly indicate which part of this code I should change in order to change the following : ( i) I want line numbers from 1 to 60 in a page ( ii) the line number 1 should start earlier than the actual first line of the paper and ( iii) line numbering is a littlebit dense( i.e there should be a bit less gap between line numbers n and n+1 compared to what is demonstrated here)?

Comment: In th output of the above code two things are occuring : (i) There is no line numbering in the first page of the manuscript (ii) In each page line numbers are increasing (is there a way to make line numbers in each page from 1 to 60)?

Comment: @HARRY I added some modifications to the answer.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I have one finally question : The ith line number of the output when this code is turned out to be same as i+1 th line in my journal manuscript. For example 34th line number of this output pdf matches with 35th line number of the journal manuscript. Is there a way to change the code so that every line number gets increased by exactly $1$ ?

Comment: You can advance the counter immediately after (re)setting it, i.e., `\global\advance\ACM@linecount by \@ne` following the line I marked with `% reset counter each page`. But then it starts at 2 and runs until 61, is that what you want?

Comment: it should from 1 to 60. But  line number 1 in this output should be marked now as line number 2 and so on. That's what the aim is

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want the number 1 to be printed, and if so, where? If you want to print 1 and 2 but just want it higher so that the current number 2 will be at the position of the first line then you can adjust the `y` (=2nd) coordinate in `\put(-26,-10)`. If you don't want 1 to be printed then you can use the modification in my comment above.